# How do I check if td:nth-child(3) is greater than or equal to a percentage?

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm currently writing a web page that pulls in all this data. In this data there are 3 separate tables. In each table, I want to check if in the 3rd `td` in that `TR` is greater than or = to a percentage.

How can I check if `{{opendiff}}` (which is a percentage already) is greater than or equal to 18% ( this percentage can be hard-coded. ). The row should look something like:

```
goal | actual | % diff

100%  | 43% | 57%
```

If the diff% is lower than 50% I would like it to use jquery to `toggleClass()` so I can make the row turn red (I already created the classes for these `TR` rows, but I don't know how to implement the check to see if greater than etc.) .

```
<tr>
    <td class="hide-on-large-only">Dialer</td>
    <td>18 %     </td>
    <td>{{opentransfer}}</td>
    <td>{{opendiff}}</td>
    <td class="hide-on-med-and-down"></td>
</tr>
```

I found my jquery function jQuery `toggleClass()` Method. I just don't know how to check if the TD is greater than a % to make the jquery `toggleClass()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't even need jQuery:

```js
const cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".opendiff"));

// fill in random values
for(const cell of cells) {
    cell.innerHTML = (Math.round(Math.random()*1000)/10) + " %";
}

// I set t to 50 to make it more likely for red values
const maxPercentage = 50;
// for each cell, as above
for(const cell of cells) {
    cell.classList.toggle("red",parseFloat(cell.textContent)<maxPercentage);
}
```

```css
table td {
 background-color: #cceeFF;
}
td.red {
  background-color: #FFDDDD;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td class="hide-on-large-only">Dialer</td>
    <td>18 %     </td>
    <td>{{opentransfer}}</td>
    <td class="opendiff">{{opendiff}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hide-on-large-only">Dialer</td>
    <td>18 %     </td>
    <td>{{opentransfer}}</td>
    <td class="opendiff">{{opendiff}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hide-on-large-only">Dialer</td>
    <td>18 %     </td>
    <td>{{opentransfer}}</td>
    <td class="opendiff">{{opendiff}}</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="hide-on-large-only">Dialer</td>
    <td>18 %     </td>
    <td>{{opentransfer}}</td>
    <td class="opendiff">{{opendiff}}</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Ty I'm going to try this right now, where did you put the functionality? like const cells =..... that goes straight into my app.js right?

Comment: Yep, and make sure it's run after document is ready, eg. using `$(document).ready`. Also obviously without the part that fills it with random values.

Comment: I put that in my app.js . It did not work. I put it above my app.get route. Can i throw this in a HBS file and put <script></script> ? I'm confused

Comment: You need to make sure the script is included in your HTML and runs after your page is loaded. From your comment it looks you're not sure how to include script in a webpage. If that is the case, you really need to google some basics of HTML/javascript first.

Comment: `<script>
   $(document).ready(function () {
      // Cell Logic
                        const cells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".opendiff"));

                        // I set 50  for red values
                        const maxPercentage = 50;
                        // for each cell, as above
                        for (const cell of cells) {
                            cell.classList.toggle("red", parseFloat(cell.textContent) < maxPercentage);
                        }
                    });
                </script>`

What am I missing?

Comment: that script is in my header just as I posted. Should that toggle the class to td.red ? I added the ready function so when it's ready it does the check for %

Comment: @Christopher Any errors in the console? Maybe you could add `console.log(cell)` for each cell in the loop to see if it runs at all. Anyway, better put the script before `</body>` since it has to wait anyway.

Comment: I'm in a good mood, so I created a [room in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199087/how-do-i-check-if-tdnth-child3-is-greater-than-or-equal-to-a-percentage) where I can help you further. Let's continue there instead of comments.

Comment: `jQuery.Deferred exception: cell is not defined ` After adding it before /body and adding a console.log(cell) inside the script . I joined your chat room, but I don't have enough reputation to talk..

Comment: I changed it  to console.log(cells) and now I see 2 obs which are the 2 TDs I added opendiff class to.

Comment: So it logs the cells in console? Try also `console.log(parseFloat(cell.textContent) < maxPercentage)`. Are you still getting the `cell is not defined` error?

Comment: Yes, I get `jquery-3.4.1.min.js:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: cell is not defined` again. Do you have discord? To talk/type [DISCORD](https://discord.gg/dmRtgD)

Comment: so I changed for(const cell of cells) to for(var cell of cells) and that works to print information, but the cell.classlist,toggle doesn't do anything